# How can I choose the right multiple?

Tags: c++, algorithm, rounding

Let say I've a list of values that are multiplied by 91,875 and rounded using [Round to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) (aka Banker's Rounding) method. Here's the first 20 multiples:

```
0           0
91,875      92
183,75      184
275,625     276
367,5       368
459,375     459
551,25      551
643,125     643
735         735
826,875     827
918,75      919
1010,625    1011
1102,5      1102
1194,375    1194
1286,25     1286
1378,125    1378
1470        1470
1561,875    1562
1653,75     1654
1745,625    1746
```

Suppose that in between those values, my system receives other values. I need to check which of them are multiple of my original `91,875` step and which aren't.

Example. From the list I got:

```
3583 (before rounding it was 91,875 * 39 = 3583,125)
3584
```

in this case, I know that the value to choose is only 3583 since:

```
lrint(91,875 * 39) = 3583
```

and discard 3584, which is just a value in between 3583 and the next step:

```
lrint(91,875 * 39) = 3583
lrint(91,875 * 40) = 3675
```

How can I select it? I don't have `39` and `40` when I got the values. I've tried with:

```
int times = round(currentSample / samplesPerPulse);
double diff = abs(samplesPerPulse * times - currentSample);

if (diff < 1) {
    ... do somethings
}
```

where `currentSample` are 3583 and 3584 and `samplesPerPulse` 91,875, but even with 3584 `diff` is lower than 1.

Comment: Why do not you divide you suspected value by 91,875, multiply back, round, and compare the result to the input?

Comment: @Michael: I don't have the "39" and "40" when I got my values, so I don't know to "how much" I should multiply back!

Comment: lrint(floor(input / 91875) * 91875) == input ?   lrint(ceil(input / 91875) * 91875) == input ?

Comment: So you said to suggest the limit up/down and if "any" of it got the values its the correct value? In fact it seems to works for these values: http://cpp.sh/4wqum .`3584` and `256` will be discarded (which is correct). Or are you saying somethings different?

Comment: You understood correctly.

Comment: @Michael: if you add the answer, I'll add Accepted to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
if((lrint(floor(currentSample / samplesPerPulse) * samplesPerPulse) == currentSample) or
   (lrint(ceil(currentSample / samplesPerPulse) * samplesPerPulse) == currentSample)
  )
{
   .... do something
}
```